# Grouping and concatenating values in list

Tags: visualforce, integration, list

My current data in a List of custom data type :

```
Name      City  Email      Phone  Plan

Jessica   NY    A@cnn.com  5454   Gold
Hannah    SF    H@cnn.com  2323   Silver
Jessica   NY    A@cnn.com  5454   Bronze
Clay      LA    C@cnn.com  7678   Bronze
Hannah    SF    H@cnn.com  2323   Gold
```

How I want :

```
Name      City  Email      Phone  Plan

Jessica   NY    A@cnn.com  5454   Gold;Bronze
Hannah    SF    H@cnn.com  2323   Silver;Gold
Clay      LA    C@cnn.com  7678   Bronze
```

i.e records having same Name/City/Email/Phone  be grouped together .

Trial - I have created a map Name+City+Email+Phone as key .

Any example on how to proceed and if this can be concatenated with ; ?
List is obtained by parsing xml response from a callout

Updated :

```
If(AccountList != null && AccountList.size() > 0) {                           
  for(ClassName.InnerClassObject myRec :AccountList){


    String tempKey = myRec.Name + myRec.Role + myRec.Email + myRec.Phone;

      if(AccountTeamMap.containsKey(tempKey)) {
         AccountTeamMap.put(tempKey,AccountTeamMap.get(tempKey) + ';' + myRec.Product);                           


       }
        else
           {
            AccountTeamMap.put(tempKey,myRec.Product);

           }

       } 


      List<ClassName.InnerClassObject> mergedProductsContacts = new List<ClassName.InnerClassObject>();

                    for(String accTeamKey : AccountTeamMap.keySet()){
                        ClassName.InnerClassObject tempCuctCon = new ClassName.InnerClassObject();
                        List<String> splitKey = accTeamKey.Split('-');
                        tempCuctCon.Name = splitKey[0];
                        tempCuctCon.Role = splitKey[1];
                        tempCuctCon.Email = splitKey[2];
                        tempCuctCon.Phone = splitKey[3];
                        tempCuctCon.Product = AccountTeamMap.get(accTeamKey);
                        mergedProductsContacts.add(tempCuctCon);
                    }


                    response.NewAccountList = mergedProductsContacts;
```

Comment: why not just add the list to the set? set do not allow dupes    raydehler.com/cloud/clod/apex-convert-from-list-to-set-and-vice-versa.html

Comment: The page is not available . Also , will that help my cause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my approach without double looping and `String.join()`

```
Map<String, String> finalMap = new Map<String, String>();

for(MyClass myRec :inputDataList){

    String tempKey = myRec.Name + myRec.City + myRec.Email + myRec.Phone;
    //check key exists 
    if(finalMap.containsKey(tempKey))
    {
        //take previous value and append ';' before putting current value
        finalMap.put(tempKey,finalMap.get(tempKey) + ';' + myRec.Plan);
    }
    else
    {
        finalMap.put(tempKey,myRec.Plan);
    }
}
```

**Update**

You are looping through the keys and splitting like this at your updated code.

```
List<String> splitKey = accTeamKey.Split('-');
```

Since you are parsing the key based on `'-'` so update this line as follows:

```
String tempKey = myRec.Name + '-' + myRec.Role + '-' + myRec.Email + '-' + myRec.Phone;
```

As, your current code `key` is not getting concatenated by `'-'`, that's why the error is.

Comment: Hi Shantanu . Thanks for your help . I updated my code accordingly and now I want to assign the map of string/string to a list of same type as before . i.e of object type InnerClassObject . Can you please take a look at the updated section ? I am getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

From where you are right now, the easiest route is probably to have your map, keyed on the combination of `Name`, `City`, `Email`, and `Phone`, store a `List<String>` as its value.

The nice thing about storing your `Plan` values in a `List<String>` is that you'll be able to get your desired output using `String.Join(List<String> input, String glue)`

Some brief example code

```java
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
String tempKey;

for(MyClass myRec :inputDataList){
    // I use a temp variable here because it saves a bit of typing
    tempKey = myRec.Name + myRec.City + myRec.Email + myRec.Phone;

    // Using this pattern to break up instantiating/populating an empty map
    //   also saves a bit of typing.
    // Ignoring the fact that we could immediately place the first value into the new
    //   list means we don't need an ELSE block to handle every record but the first
    //   (the first for each key, at least).
    if(!myMap.containsKey(tempKey)){
        myMap.put(tempKey, new List<String>());
    }

    myMap.get(tempKey).add(myRec.Plan);
}

// We need one more loop to finish consolidating your Plan values
for(String mapKey :myMap.keySet()){
    // The 'glue' string here is simply a semicolon
    // String.join(['gold', 'silver'], ';') yields 'gold;silver'
    // With String.join, you don't need to worry about extra semicolons appearing
    //   at the start or end of your string 
    String consolidated = String.join(myMap.get(mapKey), ';');

    // I'll leave putting the consolidated value into the appropriate record to you.
    // Perhaps you'll have another map where the same composite key (mapKey) stores
    //   an SObject instance
}
```